# Celery: how to add a callback function when calling a remote task (with send_task)

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, celery

You can use celery to call a task by name, that is registered in a different process (or even on a different machine):

```
celery.send_task(task_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
```

(http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task)

I now would like to be able to add a callback that will be executed as soon as the task finished and that will be executed within the process that is calling the task.

**My Setup**

I have a server A, that runs a django powered website and I use a basic celery setup as described [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). I don't run a celery worker on server A.

Then there is server B, that runs (several) celery worker.

So far, this setup seems to work pretty good. I can send tasks on server A and they get executed on the remote server B.

**The Problem**

The only problem is, that I'm not able to add a callback function.

In the docs it says, that you can add a callback by providing a follow-up task. So I could do something like this:

```
@celery.task
def result_handler(result):
    print "YEAH"

celery.send_task(task_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, link=result_handler.s())
```

This however means, I have to start a worker on server A that registers the task "result_handler". And even if I do that, then the handler will be called in the process spawned by the worker and not the django process, that is calling the task.

The only solution I was able to come up with was an endless loop that checks every 2 seconds if the task is ready or not, but I think there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: The busywait is the only solution for running anything in a non-worker process after a given task has completed. Perhaps you can change your design so you don't need to run a callback in the same process?

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl Thanks, that would be bad news however. At some point I have to store the results of the task in the database and I would like to do that within Django. So I unfortunately don't see how I could change my design in a way, where the callback is not executed within Django.

Comment: Have you tried the chain strategy: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks

Comment: @xecgr I might be mistaken but it doesn't seem like this would help in executing the handler function within the process that started the task. Or could you elaborate a bit on how this should work?

Comment: You are wright. If you need to save some data in the middle of execution, I shoud consider split it in two functions; perform a delay().get() with the first part, store what you want and do the rest with the second function. It's not very elegant, but it might work

Comment: You should have full access to the Django ORM inside your Celery task. Storing models is not a problem. I do it all the time.

Comment: So is it not possible to callback the function defined within the django process?